# The installed schema version does not meet the minimum

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am updating a Drupal 8 website to the latest version 8.2.4 and I am having this error.

> The installed schema version does not meet the minimum. Your system
>   schema version is -1. Updating directly from a schema version prior to
>   8000 is not supported. You must migrate your site to Drupal
>   8 first.

It's not an upgrade from Drupal 7 to , it's and update from 8.2.1 to 8.2.4.
[Find image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSlwd.png)

Comment: use this commande line :  drush updb -y && drush cc all

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am running this site on a live server. I dont have drush enable for that. Is there another way to address this problem? Can you say what is exactly causing this problem? thanks alot

Comment: Drush is a powerful and useful tool , i think you should to install it and use it . You'll get more information.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have SSH access to the server to run Drush. The client only provide me with FTP access, so I'm basically screwed on that part. Is there a work around this?

Comment: It's a bad thing to put a drupal on mutaulized server.. :/ 
Do you have access to database ?

Comment: I have zero access to cpanel. I only have the database credentials. If you're suggesting a solution using the database I can relate that to them.

Comment: If you don't have SSH access or database access , you can't solve this kind of issue..

Comment: I just spoke to the guy that has access to the database. What should be done on the database? Think this might be an easier path considering this situation rather than SSH.